# Recommended Dark/Light or custom Theme implementation in Flutter Cupertino

Tags: flutter

I’m currently implementing an iOS style app in flutter using the [CupertinoApp class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoApp-class.html) and [Cupertino widgets](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino). Now I would like to implement a different Theme for the application (like [feedly](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/feedly-smart-news-reader/id396069556?mt=8) did), so that the user can switch between both during runtime.

Unlike a [MaterialApp](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html), CupertinoApp has no property to set the theme.

MaterialApp with theme property:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

CupertinoApp without theme property:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      // theme: ThemeData(
      //   primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      // ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

It looks like sb. is working on a [CupertinoTheme](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23759) which actually seems to be a Theme for a MaterialApp and not for a CupertinoApp.

What's the recommended way to define themes and change them during runtime in a Cupertino style app (e.g. Dark and Light Theme)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all CupertinoThemeData is an alternative for ThemeData:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
     );
    }
  }
```

CupertinoThemeData has a 'raw' property which  contains these properties:
Brightness, primaryColor, primaryContrastingColor, textTheme and so on. 
Would you want to choose either dark or light? that's too easy!!

```
CupertinoThemeData.raw(Brightness.light)
CupertinoThemeData.raw(Brightness.dark)
```

but if you want to change it during runtime you should write a function:

```
CupertinoThemeData generalTheme(Brightness brightness) {
  CupertinoThemeData _basicCupertinoTheme = CupertinoThemeData.raw(
    brightness,
    ...
}
```

As you see, you can send an argument to function but don't forget to use setState method.
For more info check out [CupertinoThemeData.raw constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoThemeData/CupertinoThemeData.raw.html)

Comment: `CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark)` works perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following package to control dark and light themes, also the theme is saved directly into shared preferences so when you reopen the application, the latest theme you chose will be loaded,use the package as provided in the read me section.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dynamic_theme

Comment: So if i make a Cupertino style app using the CupertinoApp class and Cupertino style widgets, the recommended way changing a theme during runtime is to use a MaterialApp class together with cupertino style widgets instead, because a CupertinoApp is not supporting themes?

Comment: Well I usually do not use Cupertino but this is how I change themes

Comment: If i use a MaterialApp with material widgets, your approach is working very well. Unfortunately a CupertinoApp has no theme property to work with. If i combine a MaterialApp with cupertino style widgets to switch between dark & light theme using the package, it doesn't work.

Comment: it looks like it wont work since the cupertino does not have such a property

Comment: or maybe you have to search more over the topic since I have no experience with cupertino so I do not want to give you wrong information